# Graphing google line chart with different set of x-axis data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, nonetype

Hi  I have the following data from an sqlite database to plot using a google line chart.  To be clear, there are 2 sets of data, I am trying for 2 lines plotted.  The 'none' values appear to be messing up this hope, any thoughts?  I am new to javascript, only basic python skills.  Thank you!

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Temperature', 'Temperature 2'],
['2015-02-23 05:27:16', 'None', '22.88'],
['2015-02-23 05:30:02', '28.937', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 05:42:16', 'None', '23.06'],
['2015-02-23 05:45:02', '28.875', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 05:57:16', 'None', '22.94'],
['2015-02-23 06:00:02', '28.75', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 06:12:17', 'None', '22.44'],
['2015-02-23 06:15:02', '28.562', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 06:27:17', 'None', '22.19'],
['2015-02-23 06:30:03', '28.437', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 06:42:17', 'None', '21.63'],
['2015-02-23 06:45:02', '28.375', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 06:57:17', 'None', '21.13'],
['2015-02-23 07:00:02', '28.5', 'None'],
['2015-02-23 07:12:17', 'None', '21.06']


        ]);

        var options = {
          interpolateNulls: true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "None" string by "null" and google line charts will display the chart correct.

In python you can replace the None by null when printing the php code via:
replaced_rowstring=rowstring.replace("None","null")

Kind regards,
 Nico

Comment: Lol, thanks Nico.  I hadn't thought about None not being acceptable as null, have added some code as you suggest, all working perfectly.  Thank you